# Using Tabbed page inside a navigation page in Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am relatively new to Xamarin and mobile development. Currently I am workin on a xamarin project, in which there is a situation where I need to bring a Tabbed page inside a Navigation page. Below is the image of page layout that I need to develop

[image]

In the Main Navigation page, left side should be content page and right side should be tabbed page with three contents.Is't doable in Xamarin forms?

Comment: The first answer would be its doable with customs controls only. But your layout looks like a master-details setup with a tabbed page on Android. Your have the constantly-open menu page at the left and the standart Android-looking tabbed page a the right. And why not display what you want in the left menu page using it for your purposes and not only for navigation. For iOS and other cases the first answer about custom controls would apply.

Comment: @Nick Kovalsky Thanks for the reply. MainNavigation page itself is a details page of my master details page. :(

Comment: Then well, custom controls are easier than one would think. What we see in your layout is a stacklayout orientation="horizontal", inside of which the only non-standart control to use is a "tabbed page" to create or use existing third-party.

Answer (score 0):

No, You should create your own layout.

If you're making an iPad app only, using Master-Detail Page could be an option.

But for other devices, you can't use TabbedPage like that.